# Pegar dados de uma tabela dinâmica para gravar no banco de dados

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Boa noite galera.

Estou com dificuldade de como fazer para pegar os dados de uma tabela dinâmica e gravar essas informações no banco de dados.

A ideia é a seguinte, é um sistema para controlar de jornada de trabalho de motoristas.
Os funcionários vão digitar as entradas de horas (direção, intervalo, refeição, etc) e vão clicar no adicionar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ficando parecido com a imagem acima. A quantidade de entrada pode variar, de acordo com os horários feito pelo motorista.
Ai eu preciso pegar essas horas e jogar elas no banco de dados.

Pelo que eu imagino a melhor forma é pegar os dados após o usuário ter digitado os dados
Minha dúvida é... Como eu faço para pegar esses dados nas tabelas, já que eu não tenho o nome dos campos?
Não sei se faz diferença, mas eu estou usando Java, SpringBoot, Thymeleaf no desenvolvimento

Tela de cadastro
**CadastrarJornada.html**
    
    
    
        Cadastrar jornada

```
<body>
    <section layout:fragment="conteudo">
        <div class="page-header">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-10">
                        <h1>Cadastrar jornada</h1>
                        <!-- <h1 th:if="${empresa.nova}">Cadastrar jornada</h1> -->
                        <!-- <h1 th:unless="${empresa.nova}" th:text="|Editar empresa - ${empresa.razaoSocial}|">Editar jornada</h1> -->
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                        <div class="aw-page-header-controls">
                            <!-- <a class="btn btn-default" th:href="@{/empresas}"> -->
                            <a class="btn btn-default">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></i>
                                <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">Pesquisar jornada</span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- <form method="POST" th:object="${jornada}" class="form-vertical  js-form-loading"
                th:action="${empresa.nova} ? @{/empresas/nova} : @{/empresas/{codigo}(codigo=${empresa.codigo})}"> -->
            <form class="form-vertical js-form-loading">

                <!-- <cj:message/> -->

                <!-- <input type="hidden" th:field="*{codigo}" /> -->

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-2 form-group field-required">
                        <label for="data" class="control-label">Data</label>
                        <input id="data" type="text" class="form-control js-date" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-4 form-group field-required">
                        <label for="nomeMotorista" class="control-label">Motorista</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <!-- <input id="codigoMotorista" type="hidden" th:field="*{motorista}" /> -->
                            <!-- <input id="nomeMotorista" type="text" readonly="readonly" class="form-control" th:field="*{motorista.nome}"
                                placeholder="Clique na lupa para pesquisar o motorista" /> -->

                            <input id="codigoMotorista" type="hidden" />
                            <input id="nomeMotorista" type="text" readonly="readonly" class="form-control" 
                                placeholder="Clique na lupa para pesquisar o motorista" />

                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-default js-tooltip" type="button" title="Pesquisa avançada"
                                    data-toggle="modal" data-target="#pesquisaRapidaMotoristas">
                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                                </button>
                            </span>
                        </div>                      
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-1 form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Folga</label>
                        <div>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="js-status" data-size="small" data-off-color="danger"
                                    data-on-text="Sim" data-off-text="Não" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <button type="button" class="btn  btn-primary js-ler-dados">Ler dados</button>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-7 form-group">
                        <fieldset class="fieldset-border">
                            <legend class="legend-border">Tempo de direção</legend>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <!-- <label for="inicioDirecao" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">Início</label> -->
                                <label for="inicioDirecao" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">Início</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <input id="inicioDirecao" type="text" class="form-control js-hora">
                                    <input type="hidden" value="DIRECAO"/>
                                </div>

                                <label for="fimDirecao" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">Fim</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <input id="fimDirecao" type="text" class="form-control js-hora">
                                    <input id="direcao" type="hidden" value="DIRECAO"/>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn  btn-primary js-add-new-direcao">Adicionar</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="table-responsive bw-tabela-simples col-sm-10">
                                    <table id="table-direcao" class="table table-hover">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Início</th>
                                                <th>Fim</th>
                                                <th></th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody id="direcaot">

                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-7 form-group">
                        <fieldset class="fieldset-border">
                            <legend class="legend-border">Intervalo de direção</legend>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="inicioIntervalo" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">Início</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <input id="inicioIntervalo" type="text" class="form-control js-hora">
                                    <input type="hidden" value="INTERVALO"/>
                                </div>

                                <label for="fimIntervalo" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">Fim</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <input id="fimIntervalo" type="text" class="form-control js-hora">
                                    <input type="hidden" value="INTERVALO"/>
                                </div>


                                <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn  btn-primary js-add-new-intervalo">Adicionar</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="table-responsive bw-tabela-simples col-sm-10">
                                    <table class="table table-hover">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Início</th>
                                                <th>Fim</th>
                                                <th></th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody id="intervalot">

                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-7 form-group">
                        <fieldset class="fieldset-border">
                            <legend class="legend-border">Refeição</legend>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="inicioRefeicao" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">Início</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <input id="inicioRefeicao" type="text" class="form-control js-hora">
                                    <input type="hidden" value="REFEICAO"/>
                                </div>

                                <label for="fimRefeicao" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">Fim</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <input id="fimRefeicao" type="text" class="form-control js-hora">
                                    <input type="hidden" value="REFEICAO"/>
                                </div>


                                <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn  btn-primary js-add-new-refeicao">Adicionar</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="table-responsive bw-tabela-simples col-sm-10">
                                    <table class="table table-hover">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Início</th>
                                                <th>Fim</th>
                                                <th></th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody id="refeicaot">

                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-7 form-group">
                        <fieldset class="fieldset-border">
                            <legend class="legend-border">Tempo de Espera</legend>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="inicioEspera" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">Início</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <input id="inicioEspera" type="text" class="form-control js-hora">
                                    <input type="hidden" value="ESPERA"/>
                                </div>

                                <label for="fimEspera" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">Fim</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <input id="fimEspera" type="text" class="form-control js-hora">
                                    <input type="hidden" value="ESPERA"/>
                                </div>


                                <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn  btn-primary js-add-new-espera">Adicionar</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="table-responsive bw-tabela-simples col-sm-10">
                                    <table class="table table-hover">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Início</th>
                                                <th>Fim</th>
                                                <th></th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody id="esperat">

                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-7 form-group">
                        <fieldset class="fieldset-border">
                            <legend class="legend-border">Descanso/Pernoite</legend>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="inicioPernoite" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">Início</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <input id="inicioPernoite" type="text" class="form-control js-hora">
                                    <input type="hidden" value="PERNOITE"/>
                                </div>

                                <label for="fimPernoite" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">Fim</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <input id="fimPernoite" type="text" class="form-control js-hora">
                                    <input type="hidden" value="PERNOITE"/>
                                </div>


                                <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn  btn-primary js-add-new-pernoite">Adicionar</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="table-responsive bw-tabela-simples col-sm-10">
                                    <table class="table table-hover">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Início</th>
                                                <th>Fim</th>
                                                <th></th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody id="pernoitet">

                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="btn  btn-primary" type="submit">Salvar</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

        <th:block th:replace="motorista/PesquisaRapidaMotoristas :: pesquisaRapidaMotoristas"></th:block>
    </section>
    <th:block layout:fragment="javascript-extra">
        <script th:src="@{/javascripts/vendors/bootstrap-switch.min.js}"></script>
        <script th:src="@{/javascripts/jornada.registrar-horas.js}"></script>
        <script th:src="@{/javascripts/jornada.mascara-horas.js}"></script>
        <script th:src="@{/javascripts/vendors/handlebars.min.js}"></script>
        <script th:src="@{/javascripts/motorista.pesquisa-rapida.js}"></script>

        <script th:src="@{/javascripts/jornada.ler-dados.js}"></script>

        <script>
            $('.js-status').bootstrapSwitch();
        </script>

    </th:block>
</body>
</html>
```

Adicionar elementos nas tabelas
**jornada.registrar-horas.js**
    var ControleJornada = ControleJornada || {};

```
ControleJornada.RegistrarHorasJornada = (function() {
    var counterDirecao = 0;
    var counterIntervalo = 0;
    var counterRefeicao = 0;
    var counterEspera = 0;
    var counterPernoite = 0;

    function RegistrarHorasJornada() {
        this.novaDirecaoBtn = $('.js-add-new-direcao');
        this.novoIntervaloBtn = $('.js-add-new-intervalo');
        this.novaRefeicaoBtn = $('.js-add-new-refeicao');
        this.novaEsperaBtn = $('.js-add-new-espera');
        this.novoPernoiteBtn = $('.js-add-new-pernoite');

        this.excluirDirecaoBtn = $('#direcaot');
        this.excluirIntervaloBtn = $('#intervalot');
        this.excluirRefeicaoBtn = $('#refeicaot');
        this.excluirEsperaBtn = $('#esperat');
        this.excluirPernoiteBtn = $('#pernoitet');
    }

    RegistrarHorasJornada.prototype.iniciar = function() {
        this.novaDirecaoBtn.on('click', onAdicionarHorasDirecao.bind());
        this.novoIntervaloBtn.on('click', onAdicionarHorasIntervalo.bind());
        this.novaRefeicaoBtn.on('click', onAdicionarHorasRefeicao.bind());
        this.novaEsperaBtn.on('click', onAdicionarHorasEspera.bind());
        this.novoPernoiteBtn.on('click', onAdicionarHorasPernoite.bind());

        this.excluirDirecaoBtn.on('click', '.js-excluir-btn',
                onExcluirHorasDirecao.bind());
        this.excluirIntervaloBtn.on('click', '.js-excluir-btn',
                onExcluirHorasIntervalo.bind());
        this.excluirRefeicaoBtn.on('click', '.js-excluir-btn',
                onExcluirHorasRefeicao.bind());
        this.excluirEsperaBtn.on('click', '.js-excluir-btn',
                onExcluirHorasEspera.bind());
        this.excluirPernoiteBtn.on('click', '.js-excluir-btn',
                onExcluirHorasPernoite.bind());
    }

    function onAdicionarHorasDirecao() {
        /*var newRow = $("<tr id=\" " + + counterDirecao + " \">");*/       
        var newRow = $("<tr>");
        var cols = "";
        var inputInicio = $('#inicioDirecao').val();
        var inputFim = $('#fimDirecao').val();
        var direcao = $('#direcao').val();

        if (!inputInicio || !inputFim) {
            alert('Os campos início e fim devem ser preenchidos.');
        } else if (inputInicio.length != 5 || inputFim.length != 5) {
            alert('Preencha as horas corretamente (HH:MM).');
        } else {
            cols += '<td>' + inputInicio + '</td>';
            cols += '<td>' + inputFim + '</td>';
            cols += '<td class="text-center"><a class="  btn btn-link btn-xs js-tooltip js-excluir-btn" title="Excluir" href="#" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></a></td>';
            newRow.append(cols);
            $("#direcaot").append(newRow);
            counterDirecao++;
            $('#inicioDirecao').val('');
            $('#fimDirecao').val('');
        }
    }

    function onAdicionarHorasIntervalo() {
        var newRow = $("<tr>");
        var cols = "";
        var inputInicio = $('#inicioIntervalo').val();
        var inputFim = $('#fimIntervalo').val();

        if (!inputInicio || !inputFim) {
            alert('Os campos início e fim devem ser preenchidos.');
        } else if (inputInicio.length != 5 || inputFim.length != 5) {
            alert('Preencha as horas corretamente (HH:MM).');
        } else {
            cols += '<td>' + inputInicio + '</td>';
            cols += '<td>' + inputFim + '</td>';
            cols += '<td class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-link btn-xs js-tooltip js-excluir-btn" title="Excluir" href="#" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></a></td>';
            newRow.append(cols);
            $("#intervalot").append(newRow);
            counterIntervalo++;
            $('#inicioIntervalo').val('');
            $('#fimIntervalo').val('');
        }
    }

    function onAdicionarHorasRefeicao() {
        var newRow = $("<tr>");
        var cols = "";
        var inputInicio = $('#inicioRefeicao').val();
        var inputFim = $('#fimRefeicao').val();

        if (!inputInicio || !inputFim) {
            alert('Os campos início e fim devem ser preenchidos.');
        } else if (inputInicio.length != 5 || inputFim.length != 5) {
            alert('Preencha as horas corretamente (HH:MM).');
        } else {
            cols += '<td>' + inputInicio + '</td>';
            cols += '<td>' + inputFim + '</td>';
            cols += '<td class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-link btn-xs js-tooltip js-excluir-btn" title="Excluir" href="#" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></a></td>';
            newRow.append(cols);
            $("#refeicaot").append(newRow);
            counterRefeicao++;
            $('#inicioRefeicao').val('');
            $('#fimRefeicao').val('');
        }
    }

    function onAdicionarHorasEspera() {
        var newRow = $("<tr>");
        var cols = "";
        var inputInicio = $('#inicioEspera').val();
        var inputFim = $('#fimEspera').val();

        if (!inputInicio || !inputFim) {
            alert('Os campos início e fim devem ser preenchidos.');
        } else if (inputInicio.length != 5 || inputFim.length != 5) {
            alert('Preencha as horas corretamente (HH:MM).');
        } else {
            cols += '<td>' + inputInicio + '</td>';
            cols += '<td>' + inputFim + '</td>';
            cols += '<td class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-link btn-xs js-tooltip js-excluir-btn" title="Excluir" href="#" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></a></td>';
            newRow.append(cols);
            $("#esperat").append(newRow);
            counterEspera++;
            $('#inicioEspera').val('');
            $('#fimEspera').val('');
        }
    }

    function onAdicionarHorasPernoite() {
        var newRow = $("<tr>");
        var cols = "";
        var inputInicio = $('#inicioPernoite').val();
        var inputFim = $('#fimPernoite').val();

        if (!inputInicio || !inputFim) {
            alert('Os campos início e fim devem ser preenchidos.');
        } else if (inputInicio.length != 5 || inputFim.length != 5) {
            alert('Preencha as horas corretamente (HH:MM).');
        } else {
            cols += '<td>' + inputInicio + '</td>';
            cols += '<td>' + inputFim + '</td>';
            cols += '<td class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-link btn-xs js-tooltip js-excluir-btn" title="Excluir" href="#" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></a></td>';
            newRow.append(cols);
            $("#pernoitet").append(newRow);
            counterPernoite++;
            $('#inicioPernoite').val('');
            $('#fimPernoite').val('');
        }
    }

    function onExcluirHorasDirecao() {
        var item = document.activeElement;
        item.closest("tr").remove();
        counterDirecao -= 1;
    }

    function onExcluirHorasIntervalo() {
        var item = document.activeElement;
        item.closest("tr").remove();
        counterIntervalo -= 1;
    }

    function onExcluirHorasRefeicao() {
        var item = document.activeElement;
        item.closest("tr").remove();
        counterRefeicao -= 1;
    }

    function onExcluirHorasEspera() {
        var item = document.activeElement;
        item.closest("tr").remove();
        counterEspera -= 1;
    }

    function onExcluirHorasPernoite() {
        var item = document.activeElement;
        item.closest("tr").remove();
        counterPernoite -= 1;
    }

    return RegistrarHorasJornada;
}());

$(function() {
    var registrarHorasJornada = new ControleJornada.RegistrarHorasJornada();
    registrarHorasJornada.iniciar();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Faz uma página de conexão com o banco de dados (em php)

No meu caso, eu uso sql.

```
-<?php
$servername = (""); /* nome da conexão */
//$connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"");
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"", "UID"=>"", "PWD"=>"");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($servername, $connectionInfo);

//If ($conn) {
  //  echo "connection established.<br />";
//}else{
  //  echo "connection could not be established.<br />";
  // die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),true));
//}
?>
```

Depois você você faz um `include` no seu código fonte. 
Faz uma pagina em php para receber esses valores inseridos no html, e da um iNput no banco de dados.